# Post data to a open URL without landing on the page c# asp.net

Tags: c#, post, form-submit, postdata

I am working on a site that sends data to another website and it has a landing page with a URL by using. The issue is I do not want to do the REdirect I just want it to send data to that page and continue with the code under it.
The other Site doesn't have API's how can I do this?

I have been looking at examples all of them are referring to API url's with log-in authentication but this URL does not require a log in just send in the data with the **URL(www.example.come/submit?Firstname=Firstname;LastName=LastName;)**
Something like that without actually redirecting the page to that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WebRequest`

```
  // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");  
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
        request.Method = "POST";  
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
        string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";  
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);  
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;  
        // Get the request stream.  
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();  
        // Write the data to the request stream.  
        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);  
        // Close the Stream object.  
        dataStream.Close ();  
        // Get the response.  
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();  
        // Display the status.  
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);  
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();  
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);  
        // Read the content.  
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();  
        // Display the content.  
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);  
        // Clean up the streams.  
        reader.Close ();  
        dataStream.Close ();  
        response.Close ();
```

You can read more about this [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class)